# Attenuation and Amplification - Transatlantic telecommunications cable system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrical-engineering, fiber-optics

It's a german book so I don't know if I'm translating this properly into english, so bear with me:

> The TAT-14 connects the cities **Norden** and **Tuckerton** with glass fibers (~7500 km). The cable has an attenuation of about 0.2 dB/km. Assume it's coupled with a light power (not really sure if I translated this term correctly) of 13 dBm and an amplifier with an input power of about 0.2 mW can amplify the signals to 13 dBm again: How many amplifiers are needed for the given distance (7500 km)? (Note: 0 dBm = 1mW)

First of all: I'm not familiar with the unit dBm, is that like dB times meters? Anyway, I really don't know how to start here. I was thinking of looking at this problem in such a way that I assume the 13 dBm for example would go down to zero after 65 km (13/0.2), meaning I need an amplifier every 65 km, but that answer seems too easy to be right.

P.S.: Converting 13 dBm to mW is 19.95 according to the wiki entry. Is the idea now that you take the ratio of 0.2 mW aand 19.95 and that's it? So in this case 100, meaning that one of these amplifiers is set up every 100km, so 75 in total. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

dBm (and also dB) is a pseudo-unit and cannot be treated in the same way as normal units.

dB is a measure for a ratio in a logarithmic fashion. When applied to power we have: 0 db => ratio of 1,  10 dB => power ratio of 10, 20 dB => power ratio of 100, -10 dB ratio of 0.1 and so on. Generally R = 10^(dB/10).

dBm is the ratio relative to 1 mW (this is a convention). Positive dBm values indicate powers above 1mW and negative values powers below 1mW. So 13 dBm is just around 20 mW (10dBm would be 10 mW).

Example: 0.2 dB/km means that every 50 km we get an attenuation of 10 dB (0.2db/km*50km = 10 dB). So the power is attenuated by a factor of 10. At 100 km (=> 20 dB) the power is attenuated by a factor of 100 and so on.

We can infer that the amplifier has gain of 20 dB (0.2 mW (-7 dBm) at the input makes it 20 mW (13 dBm) at the output again. So factor 100 gain (or 20 dB).

We have 0.2 dB/km attenuation which means for 7500 km a total attenuation of 1500 dB. This means 75 amplifiers are needed (every 100 km, each compensating for 20 dB loss). So you are correct.